# How to find quadratic residues in the polynomial ring $k[t]$?

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, quadratic-residues

I have a question:

Given a field $k$, finite or infinite, and an element $p(t)$
in the polynomial ring $k[t]$.

I am searching for results of any kind about how to find quadratic residues in the quotient ring $k[t]/⟨p(t)⟩$, if they exist. Can anyone recommend a good book/paper on that topic?

(There is an answer in:
[Literature on Quadratic Residues in Polynomial Quotient ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369261/literature-on-quadratic-residues-in-polynomial-quotient-ring)
for this same question with a link that does not work.)

Comment: Basic Quadratic Forms by Larry Gerstein, http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-90/

Comment: The question is a duplicate of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369261/literature-on-quadratic-residues-in-polynomial-quotient-ring), even concerning the comments. Why don't you merge these two accounts ?

Comment: yes, merge these two accounts

Comment: I looked at the recommended book but,
 no method for determining when a rational polynomial  $a$ is quadratic residue or not modulo another polynomial $b$.
 In the case where it is known that $a$ is residue of $b$, ie that there is $r$, such that $ [r ^ 2] _b = [a] _b $,
I have not seen procedure for calculating $r$.
Is there no literature about it?

Comment: Why do you want to know about this? Put another way, what is the source of your question? What book are you reading, that this topic has arisen?

Comment: For the solvability of equation of the type $$ X^2 + b(t)Y^2 + c(t)Z^2=0 $$ with coefficients in $Q[t]$, is a necessary condition to $b(t)$ is quadratic residue of $c(t)$ in $Q[t]$, since $[-b(t)] _{c(t)}=[X^2]_{c(t)}$.
I need to know whether or not you can make the determination of a polynomial $r(t) $ such that $ [-b(t)]_ {c(t)} = [r(t)^2] _ {c(t)}$. For some procedure.

Comment: In $Z$, a finite check on integers $\leq\frac{1}{2}b$ determines the quadratic residues modulo $b$. In $ Q [t] $?